# Xcode4 data entity modeling woes - userInfo is nil for Attributes

Tags: objective-c, core-data, xcode4.2

Background: I am using the data modeling tool included in Xcode 4.2 to set up my Core Data Entities.  I wrote some code that will convert an NSManagedObject to a dictionary, to facilitate uploading data to a web service as JSON.  I would like to mark certain Entity Attributes as ones that should not be serialized to JSON.  I was hoping to accomplish this by adding a key and value to the "User Info" of each Attribute I didn't want serialized.  Doing so using the Xcode 4 data modeling tool should allow the following code snippet to work (this is part of a category on NSManagedObject, so that is what "self" is):

```
NSDictionary *attributesByName = [[self entity] attributesByName];
NSMutableDictionary *valuesDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:[attributesByName count]];

[valuesDictionary setObject:[[self entity] name] forKey:@"ManagedObjectName"];

for (NSString *attributeName in [attributesByName allKeys])
{
    NSAttributeDescription *description = [attributesByName objectForKey:attributeName];
    id dontSerializeValue = [[description userInfo] valueForKey:@"dontSerialize"];
    if (!dontSerializeValue)
    {
        id attributeValue = [self valueForKey:attributeName];
        [valuesDictionary setObject:((attributeValue) ? attributeValue : [NSNull null]) forKey:attributeName];
    }
}
```

So, my problem is this:  the result of [description userInfo] (as used in the context above) is always nil, so obviously, there are no key/value pairs.  I have several versions of my model, but I made sure that I am editing the "current" version (and saving after adding the key and value to an Entity Attribute).  Another funny thing is that if I quit Xcode (obviously saving first) and then open it again, the stuff I added to any Attribute's User Info is gone.  Does anyone have any ideas as to what is going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Through sheer luck (and after I switched my code to use the userInfo from my Entities rather than individual properties on an Entity) I discovered what the problem was.

Xcode 4 has a "Tools Version Minimum" property, under "Core Data Model" in the File Inspector when selecting an xcdatamodel file.  The value of this property for my data model was "Xcode 3.2".  On a whim, I changed this value to be "Xcode 4.2".  Suddenly, my NSAttributeDescription objects have userInfo returning what I expect!

I wish there was more documentation for data modeling using Xcode 4.  When I was doing my searching, most of the Apple docs had not been updated to reflect the changes introduced in Xcode 4.

Anyway, hopefully this post can save someone the headache that I went through.